# Tag descriptions on meta not showing even though they're present

Tags: bug, tag-wiki, per-site-meta

On the [Arts & Crafts Meta website tags page](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/tags), some of the tag descriptions don't show up within their frames even though they are present:

[image]

As you can see, the [support](/questions/tagged/support) tag has a description, but it's not showing up directly on the page.
In this screenshot the same applies to [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

I *assume* this has to do with these descriptions being the 'vanilla' SE ones, and the ones that do show up have been edited.

Can anyone shed any light on this behaviour?

Comment: These tags don't have explicit tag wiki excerpts on the site itself. On newly-created per-site metas, there are a series of pre-created tags that get default wikis. It seems that tag is using such a wiki.

Comment: [Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/craftsme/query/1296080/tags-excerpts) is a SEDE query which shows which tags have custom excerpts and which don't.